# How to navigate function documentation for a parameter that can be any type (python)

Tags: python, function, documentation, dry

I have a process that does many things in python (scrapes data, reads csvs, preprocesses data, loads a model and scores data, pushes data to a database, et. al.). I want to time specific parts of the process separately for monitoring reasons. Before I knew it, my script looked something like this:

```
import time
import pandas

print('Doing foo...')
foo_start = time.time
foo = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
foo_end = time.time()
foo_delta = round(foo_end - foo_start)
print(f'Complete! ({foo_delta} seconds)')

print('Doing bar...')
bar_start = time.time
bar = 1+1 # (or some other operation)
bar_end = time.time()
bar_delta = round(bar_end - bar_start)
print(f'Complete! ({bar_delta} seconds)')

...
```

and so on. In the spirit of **DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)**, I figured I could reduce number of lines by making this a function

```
timedProcess(operation, msg):
   print(msg)
   operation_start = time.time()
   var = operation
   operation_end = time.time()
   operation_delta = round(operation_end - operation_star)
   print(f'Complete! ({operation_delta} sec)')

   return operation_delta, var
```

And this works **EDIT: This does not work. The operation is performed before the function is called. The operation runs, but the time is always 0.**

```
load_time, data = timedProcess(
     operation = pd.read_csv('data.csv'),
     msg = 'Reading data...'
  )
```

And the time of the process is returned along with the pandas dataframe of the data.

My question regards documentation. How do I document this function?

```
"""
This function times any given operation.

     Parameters:
         operation (*what goes here?*): Operation to be timed
         msg (str): Message describing operation
     Returns:
         operation_delta (int): Time of operation in seconds
         var (*what goes here?*): Outcome of operation
"""
```

Since `operation` can really be any type, I am not sure how to go about documenting this. The codebase won't really ever change and I will be the only one to ever run it since this is just a personal project of mine, but I really want to get into the good habit of well documented code.

So my first question is to how to navigate the documentation, and my second question would be the next level of that - how to go about this using type hinting should I so choose eventually.

My third question is, is this even good practice? Should I ignore **DRY** in this scenario, and go back to what I have in my original example? Thanks!

**NOTE: I know this question may be opinion based, but I am looking for the most agreed upon or accepted solution to this type of problem so I can go forward doing it the most pythonic way.**

**EDIT(S): Grammar**

Comment: This doesn't work. The operation is performed before "timedProcess" is even called.

Comment: I see that now... Oops lol. Is there any way to do something similar to my desired outcome?

Comment: Wrap the operation using "lambda" and call this lambda function in "timedProcess".